# Construct an injective function from $ℕ$ to $\mathcal P(ℕ)$ in a way that $f(n)$ is not finite for any $n\in ℕ$ and prove that it is injective.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I need help with one of my homework questions:

> **Problem.** Construct an injective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ in a way that $f(n)$ is not finite for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and prove that it is injective.

This is what I have attempted so far and I just need someone to check if what I have done is correct, or maybe guide me on what I have done wrong. This is my first time taking a proofs course and I am trying my best to learn and attempt the questions.

So first I decided that $f(n)= \{n, \infty\}$.

And then to prove injectivity I picked two elements, $x$ and $y$ such that

$$\{x, \infty\} = \{y, \infty\} \quad \implies \quad x=y$$

Hence, injectivity is proved.

Please let me know if this is the correct way to do this, and please point out any mistakes I have made. Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this is valid. You will probably want to define the set more specifically than $\{n, \infty\}$ since this is vague notation - you probably instead want to write $\{m \in \mathbb{N} | n \leq m\}$. And you will also need to prove that $\{m \in \mathbb{N} | n \leq m\}$ is actually infinite.

Comment: Could you explain more on how I would go about that? I tried to come up with a set but I was confused as to how I would do that.

Comment: Are you confused about the definition $\{m \in \mathbb{N} | n \leq m\}$, or are you confused about proving that this set is infinite?

Comment: I am confused about both.

Comment: Since $\infty\notin\Bbb N$, the way that you have defined $f$ makes no sense.

Comment: Actually, as it is, $\{n, \infty\}$ means the set containing the two “numbers” $n$ and $\infty$. If you meant an interval instead, it works. You can write that as $[n, \infty)$, or as Mark Saving wrote.

Comment: @MiaChristian The problem with writing $f(n) = \{n, \infty\}$ is that you're defining $f(n)$ to be the set whose only elements are $n$ and $\infty$. Since $\infty$ is not a natural number, this doesn't work since we need $f(n)$ to be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, $f(n)$ is finite under your definition since it has only 2 elements. This is why I thought you meant $f(n) = \{m \in \mathbb{N} | m \geq n\}$ and had just written the wrong thing.

Comment: I'm sorry I am still a little bit confused. I understand that infinity is not a part of the natural numbers. Since I wrote {n,∞}, I am assuming it is wrong? If I wrote it as an interval like [n,∞) would that be correct?

Comment: @MiaChristian The symbol $\{n, \infty\}$ means: the set with two elements, $n$ and $\infty$. This is not the set you want. The interval $[n, \infty)$ is closer to what you want, but it is a set of real numbers and thus includes numbers like $n + 1/2$, which aren't natural numbers.

Comment: Okay, I understand that now. So if I were to use f(n)={m∈N|m≥n}  instead, how would I say that this is infinite? Also, how would I go about proving injectivity?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $\{m\in\mathbb N \mid m\ge n\}$, you can also write $\{n, n+1, n+2, \ldots\}$, depending on how formal you want to be. (For a variant of the interval-notation, you could write $[n, \infty)\cap\mathbb N$, but that's not so common.)

Notation aside, you ask how you would prove that $\{m\in\mathbb N \mid m\ge n\}$ is an infinite set. Well, that hardly requires a proof; you're just saying that there are infinitely many integers greater than $n$, which should be obvious. If you really prove it, you can try to show that the set can have no largest element.

Injectivity is basically the same as in your attempt. Hint: If $f(x) = f(y)$, then they must have the same smallest element.